# best practice of django + PyMongo pooling?

Tags: django, mongodb, connection-pooling, pymongo

I have a `db = pymongo.Connection()` call in Django's views.py for a simple MongoDB connection to store some simple statistics.

What's the best practice to make it auto support MongoDB connection pooling?

Where do I need to put the `end_request()` code?

How do I choose the `max_pool_size` parameter during connection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[How does connection pooling work in PyMongo?](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo)

> Every Connection instance has built-in connection pooling. By default,
> each thread gets its own socket reserved on its first operation. Those
> sockets are held until end_request() is called by that thread.
>
> Calling end_request() allows the socket to be returned to the pool,
> and to be used by other threads instead of creating a new socket.
> Judicious use of this method is important for applications with many
> threads or with long running threads that make few calls to PyMongo
> operations.
>
> Alternatively, a Connection created with auto_start_request=False will
> share sockets (safely) among all threads.

I think it comes down to the type of application you have and how long the requests will hold onto a connection. The idea of calling `end_request` helps with long running requests holding on to a socket for a long time and causing many sockets to get created. If a single request can release the connection when it no longer needs it, then the socket can be repurposed for other requests.

If they are fast requests, then I believe the `auto_start_request=False` works by reusing the socket.

Ensuring a connection keeps using the same socket means that is will have consistent reads. Think if you made a query but it got delayed, and then immeditely made another query and it used a different socket. This socket manages to respond before the previous. You would have inconsistent data since it does not reflect the previous write.

Comment: Hi @jdi, thanks for the answer, can you share your tip with the `max_pool_size` parameter?

Comment: Its a way for you to manage the number of connections a single connection will allow. If your app is single threaded then it will only ever consume 1 in the pool. If it is a heavily threaded app, there will be one per thread and you might want the ability to cap how many it will allow on one server

Comment: In PyMongo 3, "auto_start_request" option is gone.

Comment: @jdi the link is dead