# How does a connection pool in MongoDB with pymongo driver?

Tags: python, mongodb, gevent, greenlets

I'm using mongodb with pymongo driver on gevent based framework. I don't understand working pool connection. I'm creating a new connection instance on every request:

```
connection = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017, use_greenlets=True)
```

Actually connection taken from a pool of?

Now, if I take the connection so:

```
connection = MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017)
```

This is connection taken from with the same pool? 
What happens if you make a call MongoClient different arguments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Check out this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498734/best-practice-of-django-pymongo-pooling/11498804#11498804).

You will also find [How does connection pooling work in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo) useful.